# Single Instance of Chrome/Edge Browser in windows 10

Tags: windows, google-chrome, system, microsoft-edge, win32-process

Is there a way we can force browser edge and chrome not to launch multiple windows on every click, instead it opens the already opened window in Windows 10.
All the apps installed at system level(C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs) like notepad, cmd behaves in the same way. I observe if the app is installed at user level(C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs) like one drive just opens one instance.
Is there a way to make all system apps behaves like user apps via any registry or something.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try asking on [su] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some apps installed in user level also open several instances. I have Microsoft Edge Canary installed in user level and it still opens several instances.

I think limiting a program to just one instance isn't an OS level function, it depends on how the program is coded. Those single instance apps are designed like this and use single instance detection in the code. So I think you can't change this behavior with only OS level change.